# Show that every proper subgroup of $S_3$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Show that every proper subgroup of $S_3$ is cyclic.
So I approached it like this,
$$|S_3|=6$$
So divisors of 6 are 2 and 3 (excluding 1 and 6, because improper subgroups).
Both 2 and 3 are prime and any group of prime order is cyclic.
Is that a correct approach?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. By the way, note that the trivial subgroup is also cyclic.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it assumes that you already know the reuslt that a group of prime order is cyclic.

Comment: Thanks to @Mark

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 3):

That's **a** correct approach, yes. I think that a more natural approach (but that's a matter of taste) would be to make the list of all proper subgroups of $S_3$ (there are only four such subgroups) and to check that each of them if cyclic.